# How can I declare my LinearLayout element?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-linearlayout, hamburger-menu

In my IDE the  `LinearLayout`-tag' is marked as red and the error message reads: `"Element LinearLayout must be declared"`. I have my directory set up like this:

[image] 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueuGA.jpg

`activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_first_fragment"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_1"
            android:title="First"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_second_fragment"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_2"
            android:title="Second"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_third_fragment"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_3"
            android:title="Third"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
    </group>
</menu>

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">



<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/twitchBtn"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="124dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:cropToPadding="true"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.496"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/twitch" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/youtubeBtn"
    android:layout_width="253dp"
    android:layout_height="249dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:cropToPadding="true"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/twitchBtn"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.336"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/youtube" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textPlattform"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:text="Choose platform"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
    android:textSize="38sp"
    app:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<!-- This DrawerLayout has two children at the root  -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The navigation drawer that comes from the left -->
    <!-- Note that `android:layout_gravity` needs to be set to 'start' -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nvView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view.xml"/>

    <!-- This LinearLayout represents the contents of the screen  -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- The ActionBar displayed at the top -->
        <include
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <!-- The main content view where fragments are loaded -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/flContent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </FrameLayout>


   </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I want to acheive a hamburger menu and I'am following this tutorial: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer but if I run the program now I get a `NullPointerExeption`but I think it's because of `drawer_view.xml` not working.

Comment: You shouldn't use any default views, like LinearLayout, Button, ImageView and so on, inside xmls for menus. Menu xml has it's own set of style of declaration, different from default layouts.

Answer (score 1):

Is because the definiton of the drawer_view.xml is wrong

drawer_view.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_first_fragment"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_1"
            android:title="First"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_second_fragment"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_2"
            android:title="Second"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_third_fragment"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_3"
            android:title="Third"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

In the activity_main.xml the menu not contains the extesion .xml